# Windows 8 app, getting data on db change

Tags: wcf, sql-server-2008, windows-8, windows-runtime, async-await

I´m developing a windows 8 store app in c# and xaml for a website(the website is in .net mvc 4) .In the web site i can create, edit, and delete products (i´m using sql server 2008 r2).
In my w8 app i call a wcf service to get the data and populate the items.
I wanted to know if there is a way to notify or update the data in the w8 app after someone create or edit a product through the website.
One of the posible solution that i thought, was call the wcf service every time that the user click to see the list of products but i dont think is a good practice.
Here is my code:

```cs
 //App.xaml.cs
 protected override async void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
 {
     ServiceProduct serviceData = (ServiceProduct)App.Current.Resources["serviceProducts"];
     if (serviceData != null)
        {
            if (serviceData.ListaIos.Count == 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    await serviceData.GetListProductsAsync();
                }
                catch(ServiceException)
                {
                    var messageDialog = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Error");
                    var result = messageDialog.ShowAsync();
                }
            }
         }
 *** code ***
 }

 //Items page
 protected override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
 {
     // TODO: Assign a bindable collection of items to this.DefaultViewModel["Items"]

     ServiceProduct serviceData = (ServiceProduct)App.Current.Resources["serviceProducts"];
     if (serviceData != null)
           {
                 this.DefaultViewModel["Items"] = serviceData.GetProducts;
           }
  }


    public async Task GetListProductsAsync()
    {
        ProductServiceClient service = new ProductServiceClient();
        Product product;

        try
        {
            var wcfCall = await service.GetListaAsync();

            foreach (var item in wcfCall.List)
            {
                map product
                this.ListaIos.Add(product);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could try using callback services in WCF (see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx "What You Need To Know About One-Way Calls, Callbacks, And Events"). But, for a more modern technology, I would look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).